# Нижний отступ (margin) выходит за границы родителя

Tags: css

Блока внутри `.content`. имеет отступ. Верхняя часть отступа находится в родителе, а нижняя выходит из него. Почему и как это исправить?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

main {
  background-color: #f5f2f2;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6vw;
  z-index: 102;
  padding: 8px 55px;
  background: #fff;
}

.obj {
  margin: 200px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header></header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="obj"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Попробуй задать width: 100%; и height: 100%;

Comment: Если посмотреть внимательно, верхний отступ и нижний одинаково работают, уберите `header` и посмотрите что получится или, к примеру, замените `sticky` на `fixed`

Comment: Я знаю, что он одинаково работает. Вот только это не меняет сути.

Comment: Так что должно быть - оба внутри или оба снаружи?

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы отступы были внутри. Я это поведение ожидаю. Но не получаю.

Comment: Может задать `.content ` `padding: 200px 0;` а `.obj` `margin: auto;`, Такой результат должен быть?

Comment: Со `sticky` баг на баге, я не понимаю почему верхний margin работает как padding

Comment: С отступом получилось. Спасибо :)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Мне кажется это больше костыль чем решение, я подписался на этот пост может кто объяснит что с margin не так.

Comment: @Greg-- нету никаких костылей, когда есть margin, то элементы отодвигают друг друга и за ними виден цвет background от body

Comment: @МихаилКамахин понял, только фон не body а main, не внимательно посмотрел, что цвет фона задан не .content а main

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так и все будет норм)

```
.content {
display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не суйте `margin` куда не надо и будет всё нормально.
`margin` - это внешний отступ, которой отодвигает другие элементы
`padding` - внутренний отступ, внутри элемента

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
}

main {
  background-color: #f5f2f2;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6vw;
  z-index: 102;
  padding: 8px 55px;
  background: #fff;
}

.content {
  padding: 200px 0;
}

.obj {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header></header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="obj"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```